# Poner una condición dentro de la conditional de un line breakpoint en eclipse-java

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy intentando depurar mi código y para ello he creado un punto de interrupción con una condición que es que cuando sea un número concreto pare. Me ha estado funcionando correctamente pero con el problema de que cuando esa variable está obteniendo un valor a null, eclipse para la depuración y me muestra un mensaje de error en la conditional diciéndome que el valor llega a null.

Lo que he pensando entonces es en ese punto comprobar primero si el valor es null y luego hacer la comprobación del código en caso de que no sea null, pero no se como ponerlo. De momento lo estoy probando así entre otras maneras que ya probé pero sin éxito ninguna. Les dejo una imagen de como lo estoy dejando actualmente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe si es posible lo que quiero hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es como cualquier condición en Java:

```
bean !=null && bean.getCodDep()!=null && bean.getCodDep().equals("...")
```